# Add a button to jump to the bottom of /reputation for tablet/smartphone users

Tags: feature-request, reputation

Would it be possible to add a link to #bottom at the top of /reputation? It's pretty annoying scrolling all the way to the bottom on an iPad. A link should take two seconds to implement and would save everyone else five seconds per recalc :)

As pointed out by PopularDemand, the devs may want to discourage recalcing by making it annoying to get to. If that's the case, can we at least have all of the other informational stuff that's currently located at the bottom moved to the top?

Comment: There used to be some resistance to the idea of letting people run their own recalcs at all. I'm guessing that the team _wants_ running recalcs to be annoying, so people don't do it too much.

Comment: @PopularDemand Even so, I still use that page to see how close I am to epic which is located exclusively at the bottom of /reputation, AFAIK. Maybe if they were to move all of the stuff at the bottom *except* the recalc button to the top, it would be a happy compromise?

Comment: @PopularDemand rep recalcs can only be run once per 24 hours anyway.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative option that satisfy's @markm's use case but still lets rep recalcs be annoying:
`Put the statistics/summary at the top of the page, and leave the recalc button where it is.`

This requires having the `/reputation` page do all its calculating before it starts sending data though...